# JS regex code doesn't work with firefox, but works on chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, html, regex, firefox

I'm having here a problem... (also not really a good js programmer, more a html/css person). This code worked flawless before, but now it stopped working under firefox. I have no clue why though...

Its this line:

```
.replace(/((<li>(.*?)<\/li>){28})/g,'<ul>$1</ul>')
```

When I remove {28} it starts working again, but of course the script stops wrapping the li's in groups.

Firefox only tells me this: an error occurred while executing regular expression

Maybe someone here had the same problem or an idea...

Thanks!

Comment: I have seen this caused by a large numbers of capture groups, is it possible to try: `/((?:<li>(.*?)<\/li>){28})/g` ?

Comment: did you want to store the text between <li> tags into a group?

Comment: why you escape an `(` open bracket?

Comment: considering you said it stopped working one could assume that they modified the behavior for the regex implementation to accept specific amount of matches like with full fledged regex implementations. thus {28} would look for 28 matches instead of the text {28}. Try escaping the curly braces. If it starts working then you know what's the problem and can start with a workaround.

Comment: Can you post a short example string on which you call this `.replace` command?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3C92/), but it worked fine on Firefox 30. Probably depends on the exact way you retrieve your source string. One potential problem is that some browsers might introduce whitespace between the list items. Try inserting `\s*` in your regex: `/((?:<li>.*?<\/li>\s*){28})/g`. It is also worth considering doing some real object manipulation on your DOM (e.g. with jQuery) instead of textual search&replace of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would   store the texts from  `<li>` to `</li>` into a group,

```
.replace(/(?:(<li>(.*?)<\/li>){28})/g,'<ul>$1</ul>')
```

Or if you want the text between `<li>` tags, then use the below regex,

```
.replace(/(?:(?:<li>(.*?)<\/li>){28})/g,'<ul>$1</ul>')
```

Comment: Bad idea to remove `/`; all you did was create a syntax error.

Comment: @Ruud sorry, it's a typo.